# Is it true that in general $\operatorname{Gal}(K:\mathbb{Q}_p)\cong\operatorname{Gal}(k:\mathbb{F}_{p^f})$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory

I proved that if $K$ is an unramified finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $f$, with valuation ring $A$, unique maximal ideal $M$ of $A$ and residue field $A/M\cong\mathbb{F}_{p^f}$, then there is an isomorphism $\operatorname{Gal}(K:\mathbb{Q}_p)\cong\operatorname{Gal}(k:\mathbb{F}_{p^f})$. I used the hypothesis of unramification by using that the extension is generated by the $p^f-1$-th roots of unity. Now I wonder: is the statement still true if we don't suppose that it is unramified?

Comment: You mean $\operatorname{Gal}(K:\mathbb{Q}_p)\cong\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{p^f}:\Bbb F_p)$ surely? It's only true for unramified $K$.

Comment: There is always a surjective map from $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q_p)\to \mathrm{Gal}(k/\mathbb F_p)$ where $k$ is the residue field of $K$ (any $\sigma \in\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q_p)$ acts on $\mathcal O_K$ and fixes $\mathfrak m$, so acts on the residue field). The size of the kernel is exactly the ramification index.

Comment: Possibly the simplest example when this fails to be true is $p=2$, $K=\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt2)$. We have $k=\Bbb{F}_2$ so $Gal(k,\Bbb{F}_2)$ is trivial. On the other hand, $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q}_2)$ is cyclic of order two.